# Preserve the order of the Spark Dataframe when converting to libsvm

Tags: python, apache-spark, libsvm

We know that the order of the Spark Dataframe order is lost when saving to storage
For example, suppose we have a Spark dataframe with 3 columns

```
+--------+-----+---+
|feature |label| id|
+--------+-----+---+
| ...    | ... |...|
+--------+-----+---+
```

We can save the dataframe as libsvm using:

```
df.select("label", "feature").write.mode("overwrite").format("libsvm").save(some_path)
```

However, after converting to the libsvm, we lost the `id` column.

**Question: How can we find the `id` for data in libsvm?**

Answer (score 1):

you lost the `id` column because you selected a subset of columns.

if you want to insert your whole DataFrame use :

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("libsvm").save(some_path)
```

if you only want this 3 columns use :

```
df.select("label", "feature", "id").write.mode("overwrite").format("libsvm").save(some_path)
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#select(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame